# Cambiar color de una barra y el texto que pertenece a un stack group bar con ggplot

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Cuento con los siguientes datos de ejemplo:

```
datos = structure(list(Fechas = c("31-01-2022", "31-01-2022", "31-01-2022", 
                          "31-01-2022", "28-02-2022", "28-02-2022", "28-02-2022", "28-02-2022", 
                          "31-03-2022", "31-03-2022", "31-03-2022", "31-03-2022", "29-04-2022", 
                          "29-04-2022", "29-04-2022", "29-04-2022"), Categoria_1 = c("B", 
                                                                                     "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
                                                                                     "B", "A"), Categoria_2 = c("NO", "NO", "SI", "SI", "NO", "NO", 
                                                                                                                "SI", "SI", "NO", "NO", "SI", "SI", "NO", "NO", "SI", "SI"), 
               Valor = c(6L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 
                         4L, 1L, 9L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                               -16L))
```

datos:

```
       Fechas Categoria_1 Categoria_2 Valor
1  31-01-2022           B          NO     6
2  31-01-2022           A          NO     2
3  31-01-2022           B          SI     9
4  31-01-2022           A          SI     9
5  28-02-2022           B          NO     2
6  28-02-2022           A          NO     8
7  28-02-2022           B          SI     7
8  28-02-2022           A          SI     7
9  31-03-2022           B          NO     8
10 31-03-2022           A          NO    10
11 31-03-2022           B          SI     2
12 31-03-2022           A          SI     4
13 29-04-2022           B          NO     4
14 29-04-2022           A          NO     1
15 29-04-2022           B          SI     9
16 29-04-2022           A          SI     4
```

Graficando esos datos con ggplot, me gustaría poder cambiar los colores para las barras que pertenecen a la categoría_1, dado que tiene dos categorias, me gustaria cambiarle el color a la segunda para cada agrupacion como se muestra en la imagen

Adicionalmente, me gustaría cambiarle los colores para los stack de la categoria_2

Creo que la imagen habla por si sola:

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que llevo hasta el momento:

```
datos %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Categoria_1,
             y = Valor,
             fill = Categoria_2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "stack") +
  facet_wrap(~ Fechas,
             scales = "free",
             nrow = 1,
             strip.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "#6A6666")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    title = "",
    subtitle = "",
    y = "",
    x = ""
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Valor),
            size = 3,
            angle = 90)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero, por que puedes explicar mejor lo que dice el gráfico, que definas una nueva dimensión de datos para la estética `fill`, en este caso sería la combinación de las dos categorías, por ejemplo:

```
mutate(Categorias=paste0(Categoria_1, " (", Categoria_2, ")")) %>%
```

Y apuntamos `fill` a esta nueva dimensión:

```
ggplot(aes(x = Categoria_1,
             y = Valor,
             fill = Categorias))
```

Al tener ahora 4 categorías para `fill`, obviamente habría que configurar 4 colores o dejar que `ggplot` los elija a su gusto, si no usamos `scale_fill_manual()`:

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "#6A6666", "green", "blue")) +
```

Por último, la ubicación de un texto cuando hablamos de *stacked bars* tiene sus particularidades, hay que usar `position_stack()`.

Finalmente sería:

```
datos %>% 
  mutate(Categorias=paste0(Categoria_1, " (", Categoria_2, ")")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Categoria_1,
             y = Valor,
             fill = Categorias)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "stack") +
  facet_wrap(~ Fechas,
             scales = "free",
             nrow = 1,
             strip.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "#6A6666", "green", "blue")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    title = "",
    subtitle = "",
    y = "",
    x = ""
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Valor),
            size = 3,
            angle = 90,
            position = position_stack(vjust = .5))
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tu último requerimiento agrega bastante complejidad, por un lado hay que "tener a mano" el Valor total de las dos partes de la barra y por otro hay que dividir los `geom_text()` en dos por que exigen un `position_stack()` distinto que lamentablemente no se puede condicionar:

```
datos %>% 
  mutate(Categorias=paste0(Categoria_1, " (", Categoria_2, ")")) %>% 
  left_join(datos %>% 
              group_by(Fechas, Categoria_1) %>% 
              summarise(Valor_Total=sum(Valor)),
            by = c("Fechas", "Categoria_1")
            ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Categoria_1,
             y = Valor,
             fill = Categorias)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "stack") +
  facet_wrap(~ Fechas,
             scales = "free",
             nrow = 1,
             strip.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "#6A6666", "green", "blue")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    title = "",
    subtitle = "",
    y = "",
    x = ""
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Valor, y=ifelse(Categoria_2=="NO",NA, Valor)),
            size = 3,
            angle = 90,
            position = position_stack(vjust = .5)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Valor, y=ifelse(Categoria_2=="NO",Valor_Total * 1.05, NA)),
            size = 3,
            angle = 90,
            position = position_stack())
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona perfecto, pero me gustaría que el texto se reparta de la siguiente manera:

Como cada barra se divide en 2 partes, que el texto de la parte de abajo de la barra se mantenga, pero que el texto de la parte de arriba de la barra, se ubique por sobre la barra

Answer (score 1):

No entendí bien la pregunta pero intuyo que sería de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo el código.

```
datos %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Categoria_1,y = Valor)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "stack", 
           fill=rep(c("gold2","#6A6666","skyblue","red"),4)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Fechas,scales = "free",nrow = 1,strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "",subtitle = "",y = "",x = "") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    legend.position = "bottom"
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Valor),size = 3,angle = 90)
```

Comment: agregarle el fill al geom_bar me funciono para agregar los colores como queria, lo que falta es que el texto de la barra quede centrado en la barra de abajo y quede sobre la barra de arriba, muchas gracias !!!